# Adding of copyright information data to winforms application build

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, copyright-display

`Copyright (C) 2019 Project - All Rights Reserved` string with other information, in my case `C#` `WinForms` or `WPF` application, usually included into head of `.cs` file comment.

I'm trying to figure out, what is a proper way of adding of copyright information text inside application build.

Any guide, advice or example would be helpful

Comment: @mjwills Hello, ok so from your comment, it sounds like there is no any special way to do it inside the build...

Comment: Its better to add under Project Properties--> Under Assembly Information. There is specific field for copyright. Hope this help.

Comment: If you're talking about the copyright information that is displayed to the user, you find that field in Project Properties > Assembly Information in Visual Studio or if you want to edit it manually, you can do that in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. If, on the other hand, you want to add a copyright notice to the code files, the question would actually be off-topic; you can put it anywhere you like as mjwills said.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed Hello, yes, exactly I'm talking about copyright information that is displayed to the user. If you will provide example of Project Properties > Assembly Information I will be able to mark it as answer I guess

Comment: @viktor80 I don't think I would post this as an answer but here's the steps: In Visual Studio, 1) Right click on your project name in the Solution Explorer (or open the `Project` menu). 2) Select `Properties`. 3) Under the Application tab, click the `Assembly Information` button. You can also check [this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/03/get-assembly-information-in-c/) for more.

Comment: @viktor80, I have added the screenshot of Project Properties based on our comments

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed yes I found it, and I've a marked your answer

Comment: @viktor80, You need to give credit to Ahmed too. Actually we both are trying to answer same thing and I have added the answer. If Ahmed dont want to post separate answer, you can give credit to him by upvoting him for his comments. I did so.

Comment: @Mdyahiya Well I'm actually thought that it was posted by  Ahmed Abdelhameed but since you made the post, I marked it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your Project-->Select Properties
[image]

[image]